# Access elements on the next page with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, search

I have a problem with an automatic google search using Selenium. So, I need to paste into google search something like 'JFK annual passengers 2019' and find the answer. The answer is usually shown at the top of the page like that:

[image]
I wrote the code to do it and I cannot use it because of the error (no such element exception).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
def search(link):
   driver = webdriver.Safari()
   driver.get("http://www.google.com")
   elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
   elem.clear()
   elem.send_keys(link)
   elem.submit()
   elem1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Z0LcW XcVN5d AZCkJd')
   nyam = elem1.get_attribute("data-tts-text")
   print(nyam)
   driver.close()
search('JFK annual passengers 2019')
```

I think the problem is that I am not looking at the new google page I opened through starting to search.

Help, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. First, when you find an element with 2 or more classes, use `find_element_by_css_selector` instead. Second, you need to wait before the search results page loads its DOM. You can use python's `time` library for that.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

import time

def search(link):
   driver = webdriver.Safari()
   driver.get("http://www.google.com")
   elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
   elem.clear()
   elem.send_keys(link)
   elem.submit()

   time.sleep(3) # wait 3 seconds
   elem1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.Z0LcW.XcVN5d.AZCkJd')

   nyam = elem1.get_attribute("data-tts-text")
   print(nyam)
   driver.close()


search('JFK annual passengers 2019')
```